# ReactJS: Filter rendering of a list by whole names only?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, filter

I am currently rendering a list of data returned from an API using the `map()` function as follows:

```
renderLocation() {
    return this.props.locations.map(location => {
      return (
        <div key={location.id}>
          <div className="location">
            <h1>
              {location.name}
              {location.airport_code}
            </h1>
            <div className="location-secondary-info">
              <span>
                <i className="material-icons">airplanemode_active</i>
                {location.description}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

I now want to filter the rendering, so that the only `locations` that are rendered are those that have a correct `name` field value. My API data looks like this:

[image]

I only want `locations` to be rendered if the `locations.name` is an actual valid city name.

So for instance, a location with a `name` of `"Chicago O'Hare"` would be a valid city name, and should be displayed. A location with a `name` of `"Chicago O'Hare A5C"` however, should not be rendered seeing it has the `A5C` at the end which makes it invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to use a regular expression to filter locations based on the presence of an alphanumeric sub-string suffix on a location's `name` field via the following:

```
const filteredLocations = this.props.locations.filter(location => {
    return !location.name.match(/[A-Z0-9]+$/)
});
```

The above logic basically says:

> *"filter all locations where the location's name doesn't have an alphanumeric word at the end of it"*.

Integrating this into your `renderLocation()` function could be achieved via:

```
renderLocation() {

    /* Filter locations with name that doesn't have alphanumeric suffix word   */
    const filteredLocations = this.props.locations.filter(location => {
        return !location.name.match(/[A-Z0-9]+$/)
    });

    /* Render only the filtered location with name Chicago O'Hare */ 
    return filteredLocations.map(location => {
      return (
        <div key={location.id}>
          <div className="location">
            <h1>
              {location.name}
              {location.airport_code}
            </h1>
            <div className="location-secondary-info">
              <span>
                <i className="material-icons">airplanemode_active</i>
                {location.description}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
   });
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Its not just Chicago O Hare but all the cities that do not have any trailing characters at the end of it, just the city name. Chicago O Hare is just one of the tons of cities.

Comment: Exactly, just the city name, no suffix or any trailing characters afterwards. Those are the only ones I want rendered to the browser.

Comment: That is the question, we have a property of `name` and the value is city, but then there are duplicates where there is a city with that a5c or q5 after it, all as a string. So I am thinking there needs to be some parsing of the string to only give me back the values with the city name and nothing after it.

Comment: So the first city name off the three duplicates for each city name is what I want to render. So I just realized that the first value of each city has no trailing characters. so I just need the first of the three duplicates for all cities.

Comment: When I implemented your solution, my data went away completely, not being rendered to the browser. No error message, you know, white screen of death. What appears to be happening is that the `!`, gets rid of it all.

Comment: boom! you did it. Thanks Dacre.